SetFirstResult() crashes in nHibernate C# for first page
I have a query that I build in C#. Assume this is the query - sb is a string builder - the query works fine in DB
 string queryString = @"   SELECT 
                                   *
                                   ,
                                    COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalCount
                            FROM (" + sb.ToString() + @") AS subquery order by 
                             PlanTranDate "

For the first page when the following code is run on NHibernate :
query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<abcListVo>());
                    rvalue = query.SetFirstResult((page -1) * sizeToShowOnOnePage).SetMaxResults(sizeToShowOnOnePage).Future<abcList>().ToList();

It adds the Top(?) where there is Select * in the query and it crashes.Failed to execute multi query. Can Anyone tell what is it that I am doing wrong? shall It be just page and not (page -1 ) ?

I think you're mixing concepts here as you've defined your query in SQL but then you're asking NH to generate more parts to the query by using the query object methods. IIRC, it's one way or the other: let NH build you the query via code or you build the query in SQL. I'm not sure you can do both.

Ty for your reply. We can build an inline query and then use Nhibernate to fetch parts of it - think of applying pagination to it.

Looks like you might be trying to achieve some kind of pagination but are trying to mixing raw SQL and library generated SQl, which won't work.
Just do it all in your SQL query and provide the relevant values when building it e.g.
var skip = (page - 1) * sizeToShowOnOnePage;
string queryString = @"SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalCount
                        FROM (" + sb.ToString() + @") AS subquery 
                        ORDER BY PlanTranDate
                        OFFSET " + skip.ToString() + @" ROWS
                        FETCH NEXT " + sizeToShowOnOnePage.ToString() + @" ROWS ONLY";


I will try this - ty!

ensure that the NHibernate query is correctly paginated without conflicting with the SQL Server-specific syntax. Instead of using NHibernate's pagination directly on a custom query, consider handling pagination within the SQL query itself.
Modify the SQL Query to Include Pagination
string queryString = @"
    WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT 
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PlanTranDate) AS RowNum,
            COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalCount
        FROM (" + sb.ToString() + @") AS subquery
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow
    ORDER BY PlanTranDate";

Set Parameters for Pagination
int startRow = (page - 1) * sizeToShowOnOnePage + 1;
int endRow = page * sizeToShowOnOnePage;

Create NHibernate Query with Parameters
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(queryString)
    .AddEntity(typeof(StorageActivityListVo))
    .SetParameter("startRow", startRow)
    .SetParameter("endRow", endRow);

query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<StorageActivityListVo>());
rvalue = query.Future<StorageActivityListVo>().ToList();


Even though this is not exactly the answer to what I asked, it gave me a direction to further move forward
